# Split a string after two characters with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string after both the "&" and the ":". The string is formatted like this:

```
Public Protection & Housing Authority: $100,000,000.
```

In Javascript, I'm using `.split(/(?=[:&]+)/g)`, which breaks the string before the `&` and `:`. How can I get it to break after each of those characters?

Comment: you can try `/((.+?)&)((.+?):)/` and check group 1 and group3. https://regexr.com/63187

Comment: Expected output: Public Protection & | Housing Authority: | $100,000,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehind so it breaks after the match.

Regex:

`/(?<=[:&])/g`

Check here for the example I made: https://regex101.com/r/vi565o/1

Answer (score 0):

**+\w+** should do the trick.

It means to include letters after the is string is matched.

It should be - **.split(/((&)+\w+)/g)**

Answer (score 0):

You can actually match strings up to and including these two chars if present, or up to end of string:

```js
const s = 'Public Protection & Housing Authority: $100,000,000.';
console.log(s.match(/[^&:]*[&:]?/g).filter(Boolean));
```

The `g` flag makes `String#match` return all non-overapping matches found in the string. The regex matches

- `[^&:]*` - zero or more chars other than `&` and `:`
- `[&:]?` - an optional ampersand or colon char.